# ECMA5 array methods - Finding the first object of a kind in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-5

Recently I have found myself using the new array methods provided by ECMA5 a lot. One task I find it have to repeat often is finding the first (or only) object in an array that meets a specific criteria.

You can check if it exists by using Array.some, but this only returns a bool. Instead I have been using Array.filter, but this is less efficient that a loop because it does not stop when the item has been found. Is there a method that I have missed that can be hacked to what what I want?

```
var things = [
    {name: "house"},
    {name: "table"},
    {name: "egg"},
    {name: "bob"},   
    {name: "hamster"}
];

var getBob = function(thing){
    return thing && thing.name == "bob";
};

// returns true not the object i want
console.log(things.some(getBob)); 
// returns the object but in an array and does not break when found
console.log(things.filter(getBob)[0]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a built-in method for that in ES5.

ES6 is adding `Array.prototype.find` for this http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-22.1.3.8

```
console.log(things.find(getBob));
```

Here's a polyfill adapted from https://gist.github.com/dcherman/5167353

```
(function() {    
    function polyfill(fnName) {
        if (!Array.prototype[fnName]) {
            Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, fnName, {
                value: function( predicate /*, thisArg */ ) {
                    var i, len, test, thisArg = arguments[ 1 ];

                    if ( typeof predicate !== "function" ) {
                        throw new TypeError();
                    }

                    test = !thisArg ? predicate : function() {
                        return predicate.apply( thisArg, arguments );
                    };

                    for( i = 0, len = this.length; i < len; i++ ) {
                        if ( test(this[i], i, this) === true ) {
                            return fnName === "find" ? this[ i ] : i;
                        }
                    }

                    if ( fnName !== "find" ) {
                        return -1;
                    }
                },
                enumerable: false,
                writable: true,
                configurable: true
            });
        }
    }

    [ 'find', 'findIndex' ].forEach(function(method) {
        polyfill(method);
    });
}());
```

I haven't checked it to see how well it conforms to the draft.